# CREATING AN A COLUMN CALLED ID THAT AUTO INCREMENTS ACCORDING TO THE ROWS IN A DATAFRAME

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to write a code that looks into a certain directory, selects `.xlsx` extension files then appends the sheets together and creates a single Excel sheet, it then drops a row if FAMILYNAME AND FIRSTNAME are null, creates a code column for every file it creates, like CODE = 1 for the first booklet it has finished working upon, then 2 for the second and so on, then it will create a column called ID, which will generate values from 1 to the total number of rows in the data frame, though am facing a challenge on this one. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Kimanya\jupyter lessons\REMOTE WORK\New folder\example")
def read_excel_sheets(xls_path):
    """Read all sheets of an Excel workbook and return a single DataFrame"""
    print(f'Loading {xls_path} into pandas')
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(xls_path)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    columns = None
    for idx, name in enumerate(xl.sheet_names):
        print(f'Reading sheet #{idx}: {name}')
        #sheet = xl.parse(name)
        sheet = xl.parse(name,skiprows=1)
        #if idx == 0:
            # Save column names from the first sheet to match for append
# *****************THE FOLLOWINF TWO LINES ARE SO IMPORTANT IF THE EXCEL WORK SHEETS ARE HAVING THE SAME NUMBER OF COLUMNS AND IN THE SAME ORDER***********
           # columns = sheet.columns
       # sheet.columns = columns
#****************************************************************************************#        
        # Assume index of existing data frame when appended
        df = df.append(sheet, ignore_index=False)
    return df
n=0
for files in os.listdir():
    if files.endswith(".xlsx"):
        kim = pd.read_excel(files, sheet_name=None,header=0)
        kim.keys()
        kim = pd.concat(kim, ignore_index=True)
        kim = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(files, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
        kim =kim[kim['FAMILYNAME'].notna() & kim['FIRSTNAME'].notna()]
        kim =kim[kim.FAMILYNAME !='FAMILYNAME']
        row,col = kim.shape
        #############Alternatively you can use the code above in just a single line as below###########
        #kim= pd.concat(pd.read_excel(files, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)

        print(kim.shape)

    if files.endswith(".xlsx"):
  #HOW TO AUYOMATICALLY IMPORT THE FILE NAMES AND APPEND THEM
            stops = read_excel_sheets(files)
            n = n+1
            stops['ID'] = pd.Series(ID)
            stops['CODE']= n
            ID = list( range(1, row+1))
            stops['ID'] = pd.Series(ID)
            stops['GENDER'] = np.where((stops.GENDER == 'M'),'MALE',stops.GENDER)
            stops['GENDER'] = np.where((stops.GENDER == 'F'),'FEMALE',stops.GENDER)
            stops =stops[stops['FAMILYNAME'].notna() & stops['FIRSTNAME'].notna()]
            os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Kimanya\jupyter lessons\REMOTE WORK\New folder\TRIAL")
            stops.to_excel(files,index=False)
            os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Kimanya\jupyter lessons\REMOTE WORK\New folder\example")
```

[This is what the code is doing after execution - I would love something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CujSv.png), yet I want it to automatically increment to all rows in the sheet

Comment: So, you want the `CODE` column to incremented as well. So, instead of just `8`, it should be `8, 9, 10, ...` right?

Comment: no, the id  should be a constant, but I want an auto increment for the CODE field, the problem I am facing is that the code is counting row numbers by sheet ,like if we have 25 rows in sheet one it does that then it will start from 1 from the next sheet, yet i want it to just continue from the 25+ the number of rows in another sheet ,the code just restarts the row count each time it's appending another sheet ,yet it should just first append then do the row count, then save that field as code, then save export as excel then it will do the same for all the files in the same folder .